# Unsure of Skolemization and Negation Distribution When Converting from FOL to CNF

Tags: first-order-logic

I am tasked with converting to CNF:

```
    ¬[∀x : P(x)] → [∃x : ¬P(x)]
```

There are two main concerns I have in my attempt at this problem: My negation distribution, and whether the Skolemization is necessary here.

**1. Remove implications**

Before I even did this step, I was tempted to distribute the negation in the original sentence, so I would get:

```
     [¬∀x : ¬P(x)] → [∃x : ¬P(x)]
```

In addition to this not being consistent with the process of converting FOL to CNF, it wasn't consistent with this discussion on 
[Negation distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914919/negation-distribution) (I think this exemplifies my shaking confidence with some aspects of FOL).

In the end, I decided to just follow the steps directly, getting:

```
     ¬[¬∀x : ¬P(x)] ∨ [∃x : ¬P(x)]
```

**2. Move ¬ Inwards**

```
    [∀x : ¬P(x)] ∨ [∃x : ¬P(x)]
```

**3. Standardize Variables**

```
    [∀x : ¬P(x)] ∨ [∃y : ¬P(y)]
```

**4. Skolemization**

```
    [∀x : ¬P(x)] ∨ [ ¬P(F(y))]
```

Is skolemization necessary here? Although the variable *x* is used twice, it's used by P(x) in both cases.

**5. Drop universal quantifiers**

```
    ¬P(x) ∨ ¬P(F(y))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first step is wrong : $¬[∀x : P(x)]$ must be : $[∃x : ¬P(x)]$.

Comment: Before step 4, you have to move quantifiers outwards; see [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

Comment: So to make sure, ¬[∀x:P(x)] is equivalent to just [¬∀x:P(x)] correct? And then using one of the rules for negated quantifiers this becomes [∃x:¬P(x)]? If this is the case, would this not be done in the "move negations inwards" step, after removing implications?

Comment: Yes, as you want. But you have to correct the first step, because $¬[∀x:P(x)]$ is **not** $¬[∀x:¬P(x)]$.

Comment: Alright, so after removing the the implication from the original sentence, I get [∀x : P(x)] ∨ [∃x : ¬P(x)], since the double negations cancel. This seems to also be what I would get if I had gone with your approach (using the negated quantifier rule immediately), and then moved the negations inward.

Comment: Exactly; and thus you can see that the formula is *valid*; both $\exists x \lnot Px \to \exists x \lnot Px$ and $\forall x Px \lor \exists x \lnot Px$ are intuitively true.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks so much for all your help, Mauro!